# API URL for categories it show nothing

Tags: json

I build ecommerce app and I use fake API with JSON Server when I use this URL

(http://localhost:3005/products)

It show me my data but when I use this

(http://localhost:3005/products/categories)

It does not work and show me nothing

JSON Data :

```
products[{
"id" : 1,
"title" : "shirt", 
"price" : 25.76,
"category" : "men" }, 

{

"id" : 2,

"title" : "shirt", 

"price" : 23.76,

"category" : "men"  },
{
"id" : 3,
"title" : "shirt", 
"price" : 24.76,
"category" : "women" }
]
```

I thought it's going to show me the array of categories.

Answer (score -1):

The "categories" property is not defined in your data. You can modify your JSON data to include a "categories" property.

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "shirt",
      "price": 25.76,
      "category": "men"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "shirt",
      "price": 23.76,
      "category": "men"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "shirt",
      "price": 24.76,
      "category": "women"
    }
  ],
  "categories": ["men", "women"]
}
```

Now, if you use the URL (http://localhost:3005/products/categories), it should work and return the array of categories